# Rest API post request to send Cucumber.json file to Jira in Java

Tags: java, json, cucumber, jira-rest-api

I am not able to update my Cucumber Test Results stored in a .json file to Jira using REST API post request. I am able to use the same method to update my features in Cucumber but it does not work for my Json result file. I am quite new to Java and Json. Hence got some problems understanding them.

I have tried converting my Json file into a Json array as well as a Json Object but it does not work.

//Below is my method which takes the filepath from the project and the URL to update my results on Xray in Jira

```
public static void importCucumberResultFilesToJira(String filePath, String resultTypeUrlValue) throws IOException {
    String jiraUrl = config.getJiraLoginValue();
    log.info(String.format("Starting upload of Cucumber features to XRAY on Jira project: %s\n Using Jira user: %s ", config.getJiraProjectValue(), config.getJiraLoginValue()));
    log.info(String.format("Path to Report: %s", filePath));
    String authentication = config.getJiraLoginValue() + ':' + config.getJiraPassword();
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    String encoded = null;
    try {
        encoded = encoder.encode((authentication).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class).property(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, encoded).build();

    //Import type is dynamic below
    StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer(resultTypeUrlValue);
    url.append("?projectKey=").append(config.getJiraProjectValue());
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url.toString());
    log.info(String.format("URL of the XRAY API: %s", url.toString()));

    //Read .json file
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(br);
    JsonArray arr = (JsonArray) obj;

    System.out.println(arr);

    Response response = webTarget.request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                    header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encoded).post(
                    Entity.json(arr));
    log.info(response.getStatus() + " "
            + response.getStatusInfo() + " " + response);
    log.info(response.getStatus() + " "
            + response.getStatusInfo() + " " + response);
    log.info("End of XRAY file upload publication");

}
```

// My dependencies in the POM.xml I posted it because with the research that I have done on SO and other websites, sometimes some dependencies pose a problem

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apiguardian/apiguardian-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
        <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.28.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Web driver manager dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Start - Following dependencies are for XRAY export functionalities -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xpandit.xray</groupId>
        <artifactId>xray-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End - Dependencies are for XRAY export functionalities -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.29</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

The url that I am using to export the file is https://jira.mydomain.net/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber

When I extract the Json body from the file and send it as a POST request in Postman, it works perfectly. I just want to implement the same as Java code in my Test Automation project.

Any help to get me receive a 200 status would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you please paste the entire class file .. i am not sure what jars you are importing..

Comment: can u give the postman collection

Comment: while doing in postman its giving null for uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer to my question on my own. All I had to do is to pass the .json file as an InputStream to the Response instead of Json Array. I just replaced

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(br);
JsonArray arr = (JsonArray) obj;
```

with

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```